# Is it possible to use angularjs 1 with ionic2

Tags: ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm trying to create a mobile hybrid application, i want to choose my frameworks and stuff.

I am familiar with angularjs 1, I know nothing about the 2.

Can we use ionic framework 2 with angularjs 1? I couldn't find examples.

I used before jquery mobile with angularjs 1 and working fine, but the performance, css design and stuff are poor. Any advice?

Comment: no .. ionic 2 is build on top of the angular2 framework. You would need to find someone to port all the components to angular 1. It is definitely worth learning angular2. The speed between ionic 1 and ionic 2 is big.

Comment: I tried to include angular1 with ionic2 now wrking fine

Comment: i dont believe you ;)

Comment: Lol,  including angular1 in index library did the job, tried do define a variable and print it in my view, working fine